# How can i simulate a load for downloading a file for 500 users?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing, stress-testing

We are doing a performance for a downloading a file from the web for 500 users.

I have written a selenium script for the downloading file from the web using JMeter.

***The problem is will be able to download file for the system once only for a day.***
I have a 10 VM's to add a load.
How can I perform this scenario?
please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Using Selenium for just downloading a file is a little bit overkill as normally people go for Selenium and JMeter integration via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) to test [client-side performance](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/client-side-performance-testing-tutorial) while the system is under the load.

In order to test 500 users you will need to kick off 500 browsers therefore 10 VMs might be not enough (it depends on hardware specifications) so I would recommend simulating file downloads using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information on how to properly mimic file download events using JMeter

Additionally you might want to use i.e. [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener or [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) in order to check downloaded file integrity.